# How to select only valid parameters in scikit learn LinearSVC for RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I keep suffering with my program failing due to different invalid combinations of hyperparams for LinearSVC in sklearn. Documentation does not specify in details what hyperparams work together and which ones are not. I am doing random search for hyperparams to optimize them but the function keep failing with errors about incompatible combinations.

How would I fix it?

```
    losses = ["hinge", "squared_hinge"]
    duals = [False, True]
    learning_rates = [1e-15, 1e-8, 1e-4, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1]
    penalties = ["l1", "l2"]
    max_iters = [1000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000, 150000]


    random_grid = {
        "C": learning_rates,
        "penalty": penalties,
        "max_iter": max_iters,
        "loss": losses,
        "dual": duals
    }

    svc = LinearSVC()

    n_iter = 50
    svc_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=svc, param_distributions=random_grid, n_iter=n_iter,
                                    cv=3, verbose=0, n_jobs=-1)
    svc_random.fit(X, Y)
    best_params = svc_random.best_params_
```

Example of errors

```
ValueError: Unsupported set of arguments: The combination of penalty='l2' and loss='hinge' are not supported when dual=False, Parameters: penalty='l2', loss='hinge', dual=False

ValueError: Unsupported set of arguments: The combination of penalty='l1' and loss='hinge' is not supported, Parameters: penalty='l1', loss='hinge', dual=True
```

If I implemented this myself I could catch exceptions and proceed. But since here I am calling `RandomizedSearchCV` and it fails inside of it I cannot do anything... The reason I am not implementing it myself is that `RandomizedSearchCV` is nicely parallelized.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution, setting `error_score=np.NINF` in arguments of `RandomizedSearchCV` seems to do the trick!